# How to use Unity's global menu in GNOME Shell, if possible?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, appmenu

I was woundering is the is a way/possibility to use Unity's global menu with GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 11.10?

It would be really nice to have it.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make this real?

Comment: Do you mean the appmenu i.e. the menu of applications in the panel ?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: The menu with text. That is just in the Mac OS X. But it is the Unity Shell.

Comment: This was a nice answer a few years ago but can we get an answer for today in 2015???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The application menu or global menu [as some people like to refer to it] that comes with unity provided by `appmenu-gtk`and `indicator-appmenu` doesnot work on gnome-shell. There is an [alpha status globalmenu](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/) extension for gnome-shell which can be [installed via ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-gnome-shell-global-menu-in.html). But it won't look exacly like what is seen in unity the video in the link shows how it works. if you want to try it out you can install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome3-globalmenu
```

[image: gnome3-globalmenu]

Comment: Thx! This is awesome to be back with ubuntu again =) Really been missing all the suport you kan get =D Love it <3

Comment: Sounds good, if it is stable enough... note that this PPA includes no package for 12.04 Precise.

Comment: Could we make it horizontally?

Comment: can we still get this in gnome 3.14 and 3.16 ? In 3.16 it is like half way implemented by default but this Oneric release was way way way more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are u referring to gnome-shell?

If yes *Applications Menu* extension adds an regular (old-style) menu to the top GNOME Shell bar. Install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-apps-menu
```

Comment: No, not that one. The one with the text. Like, When you have Firefox or Terminal, you get the "File", "About" ..etc.

Comment: Looks like In 12.04 , you cannot install gnome3-globalmenu

Comment: gnome-shell-extensions-apps-menu will only give few options to user such as Minimize, restore, maximise, close etc but not global menu