# Gnome, Make toolbars appear at top of screen

Tags: gnome

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: A Picture of what i mean]

I don't think this is posible, but if you know a way, please respond i guess.

Comment: maybe you can try gnome3-globalmenu: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/83686/how-to-use-unitys-global-menu-in-gnome-shell-if-possible?rq=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83686/how-to-use-unitys-global-menu-in-gnome-shell-if-possible?rq=1)

Comment: @arturodr cannot update after adding the PPA,

Comment: @arturodr Found a deb file on there launchpad and the program seems outdated! and does not work :/

Comment: sorry looks like its not been updated for a while, more info [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055280)